# How to save bing map to image on windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

I have a map allow user marked your location. I want to save this MapView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it's possible to save a map view as an image.

However, you could use the imagery REST service from Bing Maps to generate images. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Your other option is to take a screen shot of the whole screen. See this link on how to do this:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/index.php?title=How_to_capture_screen_programmatically_in_Windows_Phone_7&ampdiff=184613&ampoldid=184561